# Enable Passcode Lock in xcode IOS Simulator

Tags: certificate, ios-simulator

I'm using IOS Simulator v6.0.
Device is iPhone (all iPhone devices behave the same with regards to my problem)
IOS version is 6.1

I'm attempting to download a p12 via a web app using the built-in safari browser.

When the download completes the user is automatically taken to the settings app (which I understand is necessary to complete installation of the p12) - but there is no option to complete the installation. Ive read that a Passcode Lock is required for enabling certificate imports. However, I can't find out how to enable a passcode lock within the iPhone IOS simulator.

The doc I've read says the option should be within: Settings -> General -> Passcode Lock

Except its not. Is this a simulator specific restriction? Can I overcome it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neil,

Yes, as you've pointed out, the iOS Simulator is not a 100% accurate replication of the operating environment found in an actual iOS Device -- certain classes of interactions that are dependent on specialized hardware (cameras, gyroscopes, magnetometers, hardware-based encryption technologies, etc.) are naturally unsupportable in a simulated environment.  Other classes of interactions that would seemingly be 'software-only' kinds of interactions are also prohibited on Simulator (Push Notifications, iCloud, etc.) -- these are attributable to a couple of things:

1. Unlike physical devices, you do not provision the iOS Simulator.  Since Provisioning Profiles include entitlements for these Apple services, there is no (current) way for Simulator to understand how to connect to your specific app's slice of these services.
2. Simulator does not have a unique hardware identifier, so connections from your Simulator would be indistinguishable from connections on any other Developer's Simulator.

And finally there are the class of interactions that don't fit either of the exclusions from above that can only be attributable to design decisions made by Apple. Passcode lock, for example, can simply be enabled by security-conscious iOS device users...or it can be enforced by IT departments by way of Mobile Device Configuration policies (via ActiveSync, MDM servers, etc.)  Adding only the generic, non-IT-mandated version of Passcode Lock would cause intra-Simulator feature parity as only the most Generic Passcode lock behaviors would be supported, leaving MDM users out in the cold.  To avoid this, Apple would then have to endow Simulator with the knowledge to support .mobileconfiguration profiles, connect and periodically check with MDM servers (thus requiring unique hardware identifiers), and ultimately include the Mail.app in Simulator to allow for Exchange connections to be setup to enforce ActiveSync managed configurations.

As you can see, the relatively simple feature quickly spiders out to a host of other iOS elements that would also need to be simulated.  Taking this to the most unlikely, extreme edge case, Simulator would become a full-fledged software-only iPhone where you receive calls and texts, check email, etc. directly from the iPhone shaped interface on OS X...not an experience Apple would like for users to have even though those users are their 3rd-party developers.

Though there are some interactions we can easily deduce the rationale for their omission from the simulator, only Apple *really* knows why they elected to exclude other interactions from Simulator.

So, back to your questions:

*Is this a simulator specific restriction?*

Yes, this is currently not supported in iOS Simulator as of Xcode 4.6.2.

*Can I overcome it?*

To the best of my knowledge, no.

I do, however, think that your lurking question about installing a Certificate in Simulator is something that you can do something about -- In fact, I installed a self-signed certificate authority into my Simulator to do some security testing about 2 months ago based in large part to some of the work presented by the Developers of the [Charles web proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/ssl-connections-from-within-iphone-applications/).

If you download their shell scripts you can see how they injected self-signed certificates into the Simulator keystore -- assuming your ultimate goal is to get a certificate installed, you may be able to apply a similar process to your own certificate.

**Do make sure to backup the default keystore; It would be really easy to accidentally break the binary data in that file and render your Simulator useless for all SSL connections.**

**As is likely tacitly understood, this is not a supported operation in iOS Simulator -- tweak Simulator at your own risk.**

Good luck, and if all else fails, push your app to device where you can definitely get a certificate installed.

Comment: Even to this day I don't see the setup process for Passcode in iOS simulator :(